# Typescript doesn't compile

Tags: typescript

I work only with TypeScript.

I execute tsc right but when I do

```
npm start
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR in ./app/app.ts 4:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     // starting a new game
|     var messagesElement = document.getElementById('messages');
>     messagesElement!.innerText = 'Welcome to MultiMath! Starting new game...';  
|   }
|   document.getElementById('startGame')!.addEventListener('click', startGame);
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

It looks like how type ts is not recognized.

Comment: Well, there's a URL in the error message. Did you visit https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders ?

Comment: I have already visited that URL, but it seem my project doesn't have the right dependencies. I have started today with typescript and I don't know yet how to look for information

Answer (score 0):

You're using [optional chaining](http://optional%20chaining), which is only supported by version 3.7 and above.
Which version of TypeScript do you use? (`tsc -v`).

If the version you use is lower, upgrade your TypeScript compiler:

`npm i -g typescript` (for global installation)

or

`npm i typescript` (for local, project-specific installation)